# Azure Form Recognizer compose model error

Tags: python, azure-form-recognizer

I'm attempting to create a composed model in python 3.8.5 using azure-ai-formrecognizer==3.1.0b1.

I recently re-trained one of the sub-models and now I am receiving the following error when I attempt to create the updated composed model:

```
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (3200) Internal error during model reading for model f13d268e-336e-4104-9625-ad0a5463dc82.
Invalid model created with ID=7909e991-8f39-4605-9558-eda89291ddb9
```

The model with id f13d268e-336e-4104-9625-ad0a5463dc82 works fine, however, when I use it individually.  Here is the json for the model that I am able to download from https://fott-preview.azurewebsites.net/

```
{"modelInfo":{"modelId":"f13d268e-336e-4104-9625-ad0a5463dc82","modelName":"cigna_1","attributes":{"isComposed":false},"status":"ready","createdDateTime":"2021-05-08T01:03:35Z","lastUpdatedDateTime":"2021-05-08T01:03:42Z"},"trainResult":{"averageModelAccuracy":0.608,"trainingDocuments":[{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_0.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_1.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_10.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_11.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_12.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_13.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_14.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_15.pdf","pages":2,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_16.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_2.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_3.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_4.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_5.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_6.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_7.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_8.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"},{"documentName":"cigna_1/cigna_1_9.pdf","pages":1,"status":"succeeded"}],"fields":[{"fieldName":"Group","accuracy":0.529},{"fieldName":"GroupID","accuracy":0.353},{"fieldName":"InsuranceCompany","accuracy":0.941},{"fieldName":"Network","accuracy":0.706},{"fieldName":"Provider","accuracy":0.588},{"fieldName":"ProviderID","accuracy":0.529}],"errors":[]}}
```

As you can see it is *not* itself a composed model.  It previously was able to be composed just fine.  I recently retrained it with some new training examples.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated to azure-ai-formrecognizer==3.1.0b4, and now the composed model was created correctly.